# Detecting whether a GPS coordinate falls in a rectangle

Tags: math, geometry

Is there a nice piece of code (*simple* if statements that are easy to understand) to test whether a coordinate (lat, lng) falls in a rectangle (if bottomLeft and topRight  coordinates are known).

UPD: I did find some similar questions but they the answers look hacky.

Comment: Sounds like homework.

Comment: This site (almost) requires questioners to show some of their previous work. Please link to or quote some of the "similar questions" and explain just how the answers are not appropriate for you.

Comment: We don't ask for code at SO. We show what we tried and ask for help on getting it working

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check:

- that the target latitude if between these of the `bottomLeft` and `topRight` points
- same for longitude

If both conditions are true, the target point falls inside the rectangle.

PS: the Earth is (more or less) spherical, so if the `bottomLeft` and `topRight` points are far away, the rectangle will have rounded sides.